# Do we always need to check if post and get variables are set before reading/using them?

Tags: php, http, variables

Consider the following example:

```
if ( isset($_POST['type']) && 'page' == $_POST['type'] )
    return;
```

Do we need the `isset($_POST['type'])` check?

From what I've seen so far the following has the seem result:

```
if ( 'page' == $_POST['type'] )
    return;
```

Or can this cause problems in certain situations?

Comment: If error_reporting is enabled and $_POST['type'] is not set than it generates undefined index warning.

Comment: I always check with isset, after the isset I check with trim if it is null or not.

Comment: isset() and empty are the important functions of php ..

issset() only checks the variable is not null but empty() checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc..

using both function is a mature tatics for solving pblms ..

please read php  manual for more

Comment: Yes I know it's good and also the reasons why, but in this particular case it doesn't seem do anything. Could there be a case where `if ( 'page' == $_POST['type'] )` would fail?    
Edit: Allready answered by @Rakesh Sojitra and @Anuraj P.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "`isset`" is right approach otherwise it will throw warning: "index type is undefined". Also it checks whether array is empty or not.

`isset()` function will serve the replacement of two functions

```
if(!empty(your_array) && array_key_exists('type',$POST['type']))
```

So use this check to avoid further complications

Comment: Actually `empty` implies `isset` and adds extra checks

Comment: Using `empty` will discard any value that is equal (not equivalent) to false `$var == false`. Check it out at http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

This can cause problems like error notice: [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

You can use `array_key_exists` instead of `isset`. `array_key_exists` method will definitely tell you if a key exists in an array, whereas isset will only return true if the key/variable exists and is not null

There is another important difference.`isset` doesn't complain when $x does not exist, while `array_key_exists` does.

```
$x = [
    'key1' => 'abcd',
    'key2' =>  null
];

isset($x['key1']);             // true
array_key_exists('key1', $x);  // true

isset($x['key2']);             // false
array_key_exists('key2', $x);  // true
```

Comment: Only using `array_key_exists` alone will not serve purpose. Yu have to apply one more check `empty` with it. Because array_key_exists will not check whether your array is empty or not. Once you pass on check `if(!empty(my_array)` then check for its key whether that array has key or not.